# how to fill a web text box without using selenium

Tags: python, search, textbox, screen-scraping

I am trying to get some information about a list of things . and I can only do that by pasting every element of that list on a text box and pressing enter on a specific website.
I can not use selenium for that for reasons I cant explain . And I didn't really found something useful on the internet .  I need to use python for that.

like this website where I have to click on the magnifier and the fill out the text box  and pressing enter after.

https://www.flashscore.com/

Thanks!

Comment: Which """box"""? I can't see any box on site

Comment: what can you use? maybe pywinauto?

Comment: after you click the magnifying glass there is a text box that says "type to search here "